# How do I configure database and parameters as the app passes from dev, to test to prod?

Tags: cloudbees

I am trying to set up my first Cloudbees app.

Is there documentation or tutorial that shows how to

a) set variables depending on the environment. e.g. restful end point URLs have to change depending on dev, test or prod

b) initialize the database. We want to initialise the database when we do from dev to test, but not from test to prod.

Thanks

Comment: what web framework are you using BTW? There are several answers depending on this!

Comment: I am deploying spring java and angularjs apps - is that what you mean by web framework?

Answer (score 1):

a) you should use [application parameters](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Configuration+Parameters) for your DEV/TEST/PROD application to have adequate URL set as system property. parameters are tied to an application ID, so a common pattern is to deploy same binary to myapp-dev, myapp-test, myapp-prod, but change the configuration bindings.

b) use a boolean system property to disable the database migration process on production.

Comment: you can orchestrate  it all from Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I can get that process working for my Spring Tomcat test app. It makes more sense to use Jenkins, I am thinking.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. I can get that process working for my Spring Tomcat test app. It makes more sense to use Jenkins, I am thinking. To confirm, I access in Java via  String user = System.getProperty("user.name") ;, right?